# Coupon to trigger cart rule + specific price rule

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

When a customer adds a specific coupon, it triggers a cart rule, I want on top of that to apply a discount price on a specific product in the cart.

Example

**cart before**:

product A = 10€

product B = 20€

cart total price = 30€

*action : 1 coupon is added*

**cart after**:

product A = 10€

product B = 20€ -50% = 10€

voucher = -5€

cart total price = 15€

Do you have any ideas on how to do that ?